# How to install a package from a repository which is missing some architectures?

Tags: debian, apt, dpkg

I tried to install syncthing on Debian Jessie (i386 architecture) following [these steps](https://apt.syncthing.net/):

```
curl -s https://syncthing.net/release-key.txt | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb http://apt.syncthing.net/ syncthing release" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/syncthing.list
sudo apt-get update
```

At this point, `apt-get` fails with the following message:

> W: Failed to fetch http://apt.syncthing.net/dists/syncthing/InRelease  Unable to find expected entry 'release/binary-arm64/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

Now, I do have `arm64` as a foreign architecture, and `syncthing` seems to miss packages for it. That shouldn't be a problem, since I only want to install syncthing on my host architecture, `i386`.

How can I proceed with the installation without removing `arm64` from my foreign architectures?

Comment: Not sure if it will work, but you could try editing the syncthing entry in sources.list to 'deb [arch=i386] http//apt.syncthing.net/ syncthing release'

Comment: @PaulNordin Hey, thanks, I didn't know it was possible. It [looks](https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/HOWTO#Setting_up_apt_sources) like the solution I'm after. I'll try it out when I get back home, but I'm confident it will work. Could you write an answer?

Comment: Nice link. I'll incorporate that into the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the architecture for apt to use by modifying the source entry (adding [arch=architecture] or during installation (apt-get install package:architecture). For more information, please refer to [Multiarch/HOWTO - Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/HOWTO#Setting_up_apt_sources)

Since you are having trouble at the apt update stage, it is probably best to try modifying the entry for syncthing in /etc/apt/sources.list to the following:

```
deb [arch=i386] http://apt.syncthing.net/ syncthing release
```

Then, retry the update.